# Chrome Extension Update URL with normal "Back" Button function

Tags: google-chrome-extension

i am using this function, to change the url

```
chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, {url: newUrl});
```

But everytime when he update the url and i will "Back" Button, it goes in a circle. I go back to the Site before like that.

I go on "www.Google.com"
The Update change the Site to "www.Google.com/hello"
When i am click "Back Button" it goes to "www.Google.com" and now it update again to "www.Google.com/hello" because he is checking the URL if there is "hello" or not.

Is there a chance to Update the URL without overwriting the back button or anything?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use [history.replaceState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#The_replaceState()_method),

> history.replaceState() operates exactly like history.pushState() except that replaceState() **modifies the current history entry instead of creating a new one**.

Be aware that this api should be called in the context of current web page, so you would need to use `chrome.tabs.executeScript` to execute it or declare it in [Content Scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) then do some [Message Passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) to trigger it.

Comment: Can you show me an example to change the add "/foo" at a url without changing the history... for Google Chrome